# Selenium IDE - Assert commands returning false negatives

Tags: testing, selenium-ide

If I run IDE scripts containing assert commands those steps pass when they should not.

If those same steps are executed individually (i.e. selected in the steps pane and then x is pressed) they fail as expected.

If I run those same scripts with the assert commands replaced with verify commands then the steps fail as expected.

I am using Selenium IDE 2.9.1, Firefox 50.0.1, macOS 10.12.3

See attached screenshot and source below.

[Anomalous results screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpGyL.png)

Source:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://fe.rel-330.stage.mpb.com/en-uk/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForText</td>
 <td>//h3/span</td>
 <td>Selenium IDE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>verifyText</td>
 <td>//h3/span</td>
 <td>wookie</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>verifyText</td>
 <td>//h3/span</td>
 <td>Selenium IDE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>verifyNotText</td>
 <td>//h3/span</td>
 <td>Selenium IDE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>verifyNotVisible</td>
 <td>//h3/span</td>
 <td>Selenium IDE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>verifyVisible</td>
 <td>//h3/span</td>
 <td>Selenium IDE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>verifyEval</td>
 <td>storedVars['model1']==storedVars['emailConfirm1']</td>
 <td>true</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>verifyLocation</td>
 <td>https://notwikipedia.com</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>assertText</td>
 <td>//h3/span</td>
 <td>wookie</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>assertText</td>
 <td>//h3/span</td>
 <td>Selenium IDE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>assertNotText</td>
 <td>//h3/span</td>
 <td>Selenium IDE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>assertNotVisible</td>
 <td>//h3/span</td>
 <td>Selenium IDE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>assertVisible</td>
 <td>//h3/span</td>
 <td>Selenium IDE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>assertEval</td>
 <td>storedVars['model1']==storedVars['emailConfirm1']</td>
 <td>true</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>assertLocation</td>
 <td>https://notwikipedia.com</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>verifyEval</td>
 <td>storedVars['model1']==storedVars['emailConfirm1']</td>
 <td>true</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```